# Opencart optimus theme errors

Tags: php, opencart

Hello guys i have some problems with my opencart theme .
https://melani-shop.com
I got too much erros can you help me ?

Screenshot http://prntscr.com/erggqi

Comment: Your first link explains it clearly already why you're getting "too much errors". It says "Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!". Have you tried solving that one first?